# Searching in database from a form returning empty input

Tags: database, forms, search, string

I want to do search in my database using some fields filled by a form
but if some fields are left empty i don't want to include them
which kind of query can help me in achieving this??
Currently i am using a query like:

```
 Select * from DATABASE where COLUMN='form_input';
```

but as my form will return empty it will try and select rows which have null entries but rather i want to this time see a result of all rows in database i.e i want to invalidate the filter by `COLUMN='form_input'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we do not know your server side scripting language -
The psheuducode should be -

```
if(request['form_input']!=null)
    Select * from DATABASE where COLUMN='form_input';
else
    Select * from DATABASE;
```

Also If there are many fields for form_input then we can design
our code something like -

```
String wherequery = "";

if(request['form_input1']!=null)
{
    wherequery = wherequery + " COLUMN='form_input1' ";
}
if(request['form_input2']!=null)
{
    wherequery = wherequery + " And "
    wherequery = wherequery + " COLUMN='form_input2' ";
}
if(request['form_input3']!=null)
{
    wherequery = wherequery + " And "
    wherequery = wherequery + " COLUMN='form_input3' ";
}
....
And so on
....


String selectQuery = "";
if(wherequery == "")
{
       selectQuery = "Select * from TABLE";
}
else
{
       selectQuery = "Select * from TABLE where" + wherequery ;
}

execute (selectQuery);
```

Please note we are using `pseudo code` here. We can take the form inputs and concatenate query for each input which is not null.

If we find the concatenated string as blank string, we will select the full table.

Otherwise

we will select with the where clause query.

Hope, this help you out.

Comment: yeah this could work but the problem is form will be containing multiple such column entries and to design such if else structure for each case will be very complex.
ex for 2 entries 4 cases are possible, 3 entries 8 cases are possible.
is there any other way out??

Comment: Thank You this one will work just fine
except it will need a little modification in case form_input1 is null whrerequery will be empty so will have to take care of And by adding extra nested if-else statement
THANK YOU !!